# Software to import photos from my camera without duplicates

Tags: backup, photography

I organize my pictures using a folder structure on an external hd. Every time I import new pictures from my camera, I move this pictures in these folders manually. This process is tedious and in many cases I have duplicate pictures in different folders.

I would like to know if you know a open source software which allow me to import pictures from my camera and skipping images which are already in my folder structure. I use in the past iPhoto from apple, which did a great job in that sense, now I am looking for a suitable alternative.

I need for Windows, but if you know a cross platform solution, all the better.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What OS should it run on, and how much are you willing to spend?

Comment: I need for WIN but if you know a cross platform solution better thanks!

Comment: That was part one of my question for clarification. Now for the money part: any budget you're willing to spend?

Answer (score 1):

- **Digikam** is a cross-platform application that has the ability to import only images that have not already been imported. The feature is confusingly called "Download New". See [Using a Digital Camera With digiKam](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-graphics/digikam/using-camera.html).
- If you are not averse to writing your own scripts, you can write one to keep track of files that have already been copied from the SD card. For example, on Linux, the following can be used:

  ```
  destination="path/to/import/folder/"
  for file in *.jpg ; do
     if ! grep "$file" list.txt ; then
        echo "$file" >> list.txt
        cp "$file" "$destination"
     fi
  done
  ```

  This approach can be improved by tracking checksums or other file metadata to avoid problems with filenames repeating at 0001.